# Preventing build breaks - using a pre-commit build

Tags: build, build-process

What methods are available for preventing sloppy developers from breaking builds.
Are there any version control systems which have a system of preventing check-in of code which breaks the build.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft TFS Build has something called "gated check-ins" which provides this, by performing a private check-in (called Shelving) which is promoted to a normal check-in if the build succeeds.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patcarna/archive/2009/06/29/an-introduction-to-gated-check-in.aspx

TeamCity has the concept of "delayed commit"

http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/delayed_commit.html

I can wholeheartedly recommend TeamCity!

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a LART and beat developers who break the build.
2. Have the build status on a great big screen where everyone can see it with the a red/green background and the name of the last person to commit.
3. Have the build server send an e-mail to the whole dev team fingering the developer who broke the build.

Honestly... why do people get so hung up on "making developers do X". Tell them it's the process, and fire them if they don't follow it.

---

EDIT: because the following was too long for a comment.

I work on a team with 12 or so developers. Some people consider that large, some consider it small

We have a large screen (32" flat screen TV on a 6 foot stand) that everyone can see that tells us all sorts of information - including (in the biggest box on the screen) the state of the "commit build".

Our process is to update from SVN and run the commit build locally (about 2-3 mins) before committing. If it passes, ship it. If not, fix it locally and repeat. Since we do TDD, this generally only happens if something you pulled out of SVN broke something you were working on.

If it fails in CI you either ignored the process or your commit collided with someone else's in a bad way. The screen goes red, someone shouts at you, you fix it and move on. This generally only happens to us about once a week or so; mostly it goes red because people try and cut corners ;-)

Nobody needs to "force developers" to do anything. We're creative, artistic individuals who are generally adult and professional enough to follow a process if that process makes sense. In this case, build locally and only commit if that passes.

Who cares if the build breaks in CI, as long as it's fixed quickly so it doesn't prevent the team from working?

Comment: If that last comment was a joke - I would love a smiley or something. Now I'm just sad over you attitude :(

Comment: Ok, excellent edit, I now understand what you mean. I don't agree but I understand. I would rather than fire people have a discussion about WHY team members doesn't think it's important to keep the build green. If I can communicate that - there's much bigger chance to get the build green all the time, and a LART (hehehe, btw :)) is not needed. Make Love not War, kinda ;)

Comment: I agree with Marcus in that I disagree with dty. At my work we have thousands of tests doing intensive stuff with databases. It takes 24 hours to run the test. We are a big enough company that we have a couple dozen or so commits a day. At the moment we use CI with a build when last build finishes which means there are at least a dozen new commits in each build. I'm pushing hard for true CI which is going to mean distributing the build, maybe new servers etc but guess what?

Comment: Continued:  We won't have 1.5 full time staff who's job is tracking down which of those 12 commits broke. We won't end up in situations where a reviewer approves a checkin and then a day later the guy monitoring the automated testing dumps 6 new broken tests into the urgent bug queu. We can't run locally because it is unreasonable to tie out the dev box for 24hrs (some of the security checks take over an hour each so they need be be parallelized across several CPUs). We need to be able to push but then let the CI process determine where it goes from there.